# RegEx matching using Lucene

Tags: java, regex, lucene

I would like to find "Bug reports" with Lucene using a regular expression, but whenever I try it doesn't work.

I used the code from the [Lucene page](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/java/tags/lucene_3_0_3/contrib/regex/src/test/org/apache/lucene/search/regex/TestRegexQuery.java?revision=1040994&view=co) to avoid a bad setup.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.SimpleAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
import org.apache.lucene.search.regex.JakartaRegexpCapabilities;
import org.apache.lucene.search.regex.RegexCapabilities;
import org.apache.lucene.search.regex.RegexQuery;
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory;

public class Rege {

  private static IndexSearcher searcher;
  private static final String FN = "field";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    RAMDirectory directory = new RAMDirectory();
    try {

      IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory,
          new SimpleAnalyzer(), true,
          IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.LIMITED);
      Document doc = new Document();
      doc
          .add(new Field(
              FN,
              "[Phpmyadmin-devel] Commits against bug 601721 (Cookie auth mode faulty with IIS)",
              Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
      writer.addDocument(doc);
      writer.optimize();
      writer.close();
      searcher = new IndexSearcher(directory, true);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.err.println(regexQueryNrHits("bug [0-9]+",null));

  }

  private static Term newTerm(String value) {
    return new Term(FN, value);
  }

  private static int regexQueryNrHits(String regex,
      RegexCapabilities capability) throws Exception {

    RegexQuery query = new RegexQuery(newTerm(regex));

    if (capability != null)
      query.setRegexImplementation(capability);

    return searcher.search(query, null, 1000).totalHits;
  }

}
```

I would expect `bug [0-9]+` to return `1` but it doesn't. I also tested the regex with Java and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your field indexed as a "string" type (instead of "text" type), your regex would have to match the *whole* field value.
Try this, which takes your regex out to both ends of the field:

```
System.err.println(regexQueryNrHits(".*bug [0-9]+.*",null));
```

Note that start and end anchors `^` and `$` are implied and therefore not required.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, but this alone didn't solve the problem. The problem is the `Field.Index.ANALYZED` flag:

It seems that lucene doesn't index numbers in a proper way so that a regex could be used with them.

I changed:

```
doc.add(new Field(
FN,"[Phpmyadmin-devel] Commits against bug 601721 (Cookie auth mode faulty with IIS)",Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
```

to

```
    doc.add(new Field(
FN,"[Phpmyadmin-devel] Commits against bug 601721 (Cookie auth mode faulty with IIS)",Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
```

and with your improved regex:

```
    System.err.println(regexQueryNrHits("^.*bug #+[0-9]+.*$",
new JavaUtilRegexCapabilities()));
```

it finally worked! :)

Comment: The problem isn't with the numbers.  The problem is with how regex queries and analysis are intended to work together.  Your regex must match a *term*, not the whole field.  That's why it works with `NOT_ANALYZED`, you've made the whole field into a single term.  One warning, though.  When you make a field like that unanalyzed, you abandon most of the advantages of using a search index in the first place (e.g. performance).