# Indexing a regular expression in Lucene and searching over the input

Tags: java, regex, lucene, hibernate-search

i have indexed the Regular Expression in Lucene , Is there a possibility to generate a lucene query to search my given input over the indexed Regular Expresion using Standard Analyzer?

`org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery50=queryBuilder4.keyword().wildcard().onField("RegularExpression").matching("9876654").createQuery();`

The Field "RegularExpression" is stored as a string object.

**EDIT**

Hibernate search is used with annotations:

```
@Indexed public class NumbersTbl { @Field public String RegularExpression; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you search for numbers, make sure when you create the [Field](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html), specify it as [Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.Index.html#NOT_ANALYZED), otherwise the numbers will be stripped by the Analyzer before indexing.

**EDIT**

Refer to this answer for further details [Find regular expression match using Lucene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052492/find-regular-expression-match-using-lucene)

**EDIT2**

You can specify in the `@Field` annotation that you do not want the field to be analysed. This will preserve the contents of the field 'as is' for the indexing. The default value is `Analyze.YES`. Consult to the [docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.5/reference/en-US/html_single/#basic-mapping)

```
@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.NO)
```

Also, since you use Hibernate Search, you may want to wrap the Lucene Query into a Hibernate Query, see this [getting started guide](http://hibernate.org/search/documentation/getting-started/#searching). It is possible that you already do so, cannot tell from the code you have posted. Iif you want to get helpful answers, as a general rule, I suggest you to post *more code* . If you think about it, it is very hard to tell what went wrong from only one line of code.

Comment: The number i'm searching is the input, which i have to match over the indexed regular expression

Comment: That is absolutely clear. Could you please amend your post and add the code that creates the [Document](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html) that is written to the index and that you want to find with the query.

Comment: I'm using a Hibernate indexing method `@Indexed
public class NumbersTbl { @Field
 public String RegularExpression;
}`